# Extracting the first digit from an alpha-numeric string

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Examples of what I'm trying to do]

Is it possible to use VBA to catch and use the first number in a text string and if there is no number then just use 1?

The code I'm currently using is looking at column AC and finding a specific text then using the first two letters of that text and the right most number and replacing the corresponding row in column N.

What I'm attempting to do now is account for when there is no number in the text (should =1), or there is but it's in the mid but the location moves (thus a mid statement wouldn't work). If this is possible Any suggestions or push in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
 Dim wsl As Worksheet
 Dim LR As Long, i As Long

 mydate = Format(Date, "YYMMDD")

 Set wsl = LagoDLFile.Sheets("cid_SeventhAvenue_" & mydate & "")
 LR = wsl.Range("AC" & wsl.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To LR
     If wsl.Range("AC" & i) Like "*EOC*" Then
         wsl.Range("N" & i) = "EOC"
     ElseIf wsl.Range("N" & i) Like "700" Then
         wsl.Range("N" & i) = "CHK"
     ElseIf wsl.Range("AC" & i) Like "*CTOB*" Then
         wsl.Range("N" & i) = "COF"
     ElseIf wsl.Range("AC" & i) Like "EXOBC*" Then
         wsl.Range("N" & i) = "WR" & Right(wsl.Range("AC" & i), 1)
     ElseIf Left(wsl.Range("AC" & i), 3) = "OBC" Then
         wsl.Range("N" & i) = "OB" & Right(wsl.Range("AC" & i), 1)
     ElseIf Left(wsl.Range("AC" & i), 3) = "IFC" Then
         wsl.Range("N" & i) = "IF" & Right(wsl.Range("AC" & i), 1)
     ElseIf Left(wsl.Range("AC" & i), 3) = "IBC" Then
         wsl.Range("N" & i) = "IB" & Right(wsl.Range("AC" & i), 1)
     End If
 Next i
 End Sub
```

Comment: The first digit? What if the text string is `TEST123TEST` - do you want `1` or `123`?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I'm actually surprised SO didn't catch that title, you typically can't make it just "IF ELSE ENDIF" or anything along those lines.

Comment: Sorry about not being more specific. I've added an image with what I'm working with. the highlighted portion is the desired outcome the non highlighted is a set of examples I have to work with. I'm not sure how possible this will be beyond the no # = 1 but I was hoping someone might have some ideas. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Thank you for posting a new question in regards to the same code!

Comment: @urdearboy sorry this wasn't to be the same problem but to see if it was possible to extract certain bits using the code. It works perfectly but when I started going into our other spreadsheets there were different variations and I was curious if they could be accounted for or not.

Comment: My comment wasn't sarcastic. This is how the site should operate - separate questions get separate posts. The fact that I felt the need to comment should tell you how often people will continuously spam their first question with project updates even though the question is unrelated to the original post

Comment: ahh okay :-) I don't like causing issues. Just trying to keep everything on the level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a function that uses regular expressions to do what you need. It uses this regex:

```
^\D*(\d)
```

## Breaking down the pattern

- `^` Start of string
- `\D*` Any character that is **not** a digit (capital D), with a `*` quantifier that means *0 or more times*
- `(...)` Capturing group - it will capture the text that you *want to keep* and return it as a *submatch*
- `\d` any numerical value (0-9).

> **Note:** If you want it to capture more than the first digit (such as `string123` - you want to return `123`, you can change `(\d)` in the above regex to `(\d+)`. The `+` is a quantifier that means *one or more of `\d`*.

See this regex work at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lbgdbk/1). The green highlighted portion is what would be returned from the below function.

## Creating the function / UDF

```
Public Function getFirstDigit(testString As String) As String ' or As long

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "^\D*(\d)"
        .Global = False
        If .test(testString) Then
            getFirstDigit = .Execute(testString)(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            getFirstDigit = "1"
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

You can use this function within both VBA and as a worksheet function.

**Using in VBA:**

```
Msgbox getFirstDigit("Test String 123")
```

**Using in the worksheet**

```
=getFirstDigit($A$1)
```

Comment: I'm not used to using functions but I'll give this a test and see how it goes. I'm used to writing everything into a macro.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do in your code, then this line: `wsl.Range("N" & i) = "WR" & Right(wsl.Range("AC" & i), 1)` would look like this: `wsl.Range("N" & i) = "WR" & getFirstDigit(wsl.Range("AC" & i))`

Comment: @K.Davis Yep this works, fully tested thanks! Only wish there was a way to filter the number it was looking at. Mainly filter out the SP19 or FL19 that shows up in the string...I'm gonna keep playing with it though. This is my first use of functions so I'm not well versed in their use.

Comment: Will it _always be_ F/S19? In your screen shot, I don't see `SP19`, but I do see a bunch of `S19`... Same with `F19` instead of `FL19`.

Comment: Very nice - Regex is still like magic to me, maybe some day I'll take a dive into it...

Comment: Nice. Why doesn't it need a reference to a library, or does it?

Comment: The reason the above doesn't need you to set a reference is because I used late binding, @VBasic2008. If you wanted to use early binding, you would set a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5` and change the with statement to `With New RegExp` instead of using `CreateObject()`.

Comment: @K.Davis Yes it will always show with an SP19 or FL19 *when* they show up.  That format won't change.

Comment: @Deke That is an easy one. Just add this line above the with statement: `testString  = Replace(Replace(testString, "FL19", ""), "SP19", "")`. It's possible to add this to the pattern, but it'd get a little messy _(especially with VBScript RegExp not supporting lookbehinds)_.

Answer (score 1):

Variant without `RegExp`

```
Public Function firstIntInString(testStr As String) As Integer
    Dim x%
    For x = 1 To Len(testStr)
        If Mid(testStr, x, 1) Like "#" Then
            firstIntInString = Mid(testStr, x, 1) 
            Exit For
        Else
            firstIntInString = 1 'in case when string doesn't contains digits
        End If
    Next x
End Function
```

Comment: Nice but...OP asks for the value, not the position of the first integer. That's why 1 is the default value.

Comment: how about "int(Mid(testStr,..." so that the return value always is int.

Comment: @user1016274 I showed the way (the previous version also been enough for that), if suddenly you don’t understand how to return string from this function, then just replace `as Integer` with `as string` in function declaration part.